# How to determine application uses which registry value?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I am having a software which uses some registry value. Everytime I install this application to another machine this application forces many "agree, disagree windows."  So it takes too much time?

Is there any application that gives me which application uses which registry value?  For example process explorer.exe give filestream usage of applications.  Is there any similar app for registry usages .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Process Monitor, see: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Run the program at the same time as Process Monitor is running and then you will be able to see which registery entries are read.

Note some programs refuse to start if a registery monitor is running, guess that they are trying to protect licencing information.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645).

It shows what Registry keys and values each process is using, among other information.

Answer (score 3):

There is [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645) from Sysinternals.